# How does type deduction work with std::make_pair()?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, std-pair

I am not going to do something like this in real code, just want to better understand `std::make_pair()`. I have read [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair), but I don't understand `std::decay` well. I find this to be a bit confusing:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int*, int*>> vec;
int* a = new int(1);
int* b = new int(2);
vec.emplace_back(std::make_pair(a, b)); // Fine
vec.emplace_back(std::make_pair<int*, int*>(&*a, &*b)); // Fine
vec.emplace_back(std::make_pair<int*, int*>(a, b)); // Error
```

Why do the first two calls to `std::make_pair()` work, but the last one gives an error?

```
GCC: cannot bind rvalue reference of type ‘int*&&’ to lvalue of type ‘int*’
```

```
Clang: no matching function for call to 'make_pair'
```

How does the last `std::make_pair()` differ from the previous two?

Comment: `a` and `b` are lvalues while `&*a` and `&*b` are rvalues and rvalue reference can't bind to an lvalue so the third example doesn't work. Note that you're explicitly providing the template arguments in your examples so type deduction doesn't happen here.

Comment: fwiw, you do not need `make_pair` here. Just do `vec.emplace_back(a,b);`

Comment: Note that only the first example is doing type deduction. The second and third examples are not deducing anything, so the answer to "How does type deduction work?" is "It doesn't. You disabled it." I think you are confusing the template type parameters to `make_pair`. They are not the types of the pair you want to make. They describe the types of the things you are making a pair *from*.